# Best way to overwrite directory using phonegap File API

Tags: javascript, ipad, cordova, directory, overwrite

I am working with ios & phonegap 2.7.0 with the native file system.

I need to overwrite an existing directory :

/Documents/data

with another folder :

/tmp/data1234

But it seems that overwriting an existing directory using the `FileEntry.copyTo` API raises a `FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR` exception.

It works if I delete the /Documents/data folder before copying.

So I have a simple question : what is the best way to overwrite a directory in phonegap using the File API?

Should I make a recursive process from /tmp/data1234 and replace each file in  /Documents/data ?

Thanks for your help.